# How to merge the right side data when left side is common using awk

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I want to merge the right hand side of the file when left hand side data is common using awk.

Input file:

```
cazd0002221|1
cazd0002221|2
ceed0008792|2
croty000287|3
cazd0002221|3
crory000287|3
ceed0008792|1
ceed0008792|2
```

Expected output is:

```
cazd0002221|1,2,3
ceed0008792|2,1
croty000287|3
crory000287|3
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `awk` will cut it here.

Comment: can sed do this ? if yes then please suggest...

Comment: there is also a duplicate line `ceed0008792|2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F"|" '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2;next}END{for(i in a)print i"|"substr(a[i],2)}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
cazd0002221|1
cazd0002221|2
ceed0008792|2
croty000287|3
cazd0002221|3
crory000287|3
ceed0008792|1
ceed0008792|2
> awk -F"|" '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2;next}END{for(i in a)print i"|"substr(a[i],2)}' temp
cazd0002221|1,2,3
ceed0008792|2,1,2
crory000287|3
croty000287|3
```

there is duplicate line in your input `ceed0008792|2`.This is the reason why the output has this line  `ceed0008792|2,1,2`
if you want to eliminate that duplicate line,then do as below:

```
> sort -u temp | awk -F"|" '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2;next}END{for(i in a)print i"|"substr(a[i],2)}'
cazd0002221|1,2,3
ceed0008792|1,2
crory000287|3
croty000287|3
```

Comment: Hi Sarathi,  I have one doubt : if the input file is :

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (sort & GNU sed);

```
sort file | sed ':a;$!N;s/^\(\([^|]*|\).*\)\n\2/\1,/;ta;P;D'
```

Comment: This is also correct one. Thanks